# Privatemsg overwrites page title for custom code. How do I correct it?

Tags: 7, privatemsg

I am using Private message as PHP in a block on the node of a page so that a person can contact the node author without having to leave the page. Here is the code:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if ($node->uid != 0) {
module_load_include('pages.inc','privatemsg');
  $recipients = $node->uid;
print "<div>Contact " . $node->name ." about this post.</div>";
  $subject = $node->title ." question.";
  print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('privatemsg_new', $recipients, $subject));
}
```

However, Private message hijacks the title of the entire page, and now every single node  value is 'Write so-and-so' a new message, instead of what the page title should actually be.

Thoughts on how to correct this?

You can check out what's happening here on the test server:

http://g.hokkaido-select.com/classifieds/cars-and-vehicles/motorcycles-and-scooters/2006-150cc-scooter (note, you have to be logged into see the block, but the page title error can still be seen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the private message form sets the title directly. A simple way round it might be to cache the current title before you render the form, then set it back again afterwards:

```
$stored_title = drupal_set_title();
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('privatemsg_new', $recipients, $subject));
drupal_set_title($stored_title);
```

Comment: drupal_set_title was the function I needed. It sets it in the privatemsg_new function: http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!privatemsg!privatemsg.pages.inc/function/privatemsg_new/7. Tangent question. You'll notice towards the bottom that if the $_REQUEST['destination'] field is empty, it simply redirects to 'message' after submission.  Redirection would work correctly back to the node page if I could set that url variable, but I have a scope issue. In PHP is there a way to set that from outside the function?